# Adding bootloader to Feather M0 Bluefruit LE

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, adafruit, bootloader, feather

I want to make a custom Feather M0 Bluefruit LE. I know this means that I will have to add a bootloader to the ATSAMD21G18.

I have seen that there are many useful articles in relation to adding bootloader to this chip like

https://www.instructables.com/id/ATSAMD21g18-Bootloader-With-J-link-Debugger/

and

https://learn.adafruit.com/proper-step-debugging-atsamd21-arduino-zero-m0/restoring-bootloader

and

https://learn.adafruit.com/compiling-m0-atsamd21-bootloader/compile

I wanted to make sure that the bootloader will allow me to access the Bluetooth module on the board. Does anyone know if this bootloader will do that? Or is there another type of bootloader I need? Also, do I need a J-link connection on the custom board? can I just use USB?

Comment: it is unclear what this means ... `allow me to access the Bluetooth module`

Comment: purpose of bootloader is to load the application over USB. bootloader has nothing to do with BLE. you can't load the bootloader over USB. bootloader is what makes upload over USB possible

Comment: Hi @jsotola I didn't know if I had to set a specific module in Bootloader or if I can just use the generic bootloader files I found on those links above and then upload firmware to access the BLE afterwords.